# why node js console.log output is garbled

Tags: node.js, utf-8

I have a file named `app.js` which is utf8, there is one line 
    console.log('啊防守打法');

When I run command line: node app.js, the output is like ���. Can anyone help me show this correctly correctly?

Comment: which version of node.js you r running?

Comment: version is v6.4.0

Comment: hmmm... i run it on my terminal and works just fine

Comment: Node 6.2.2, works as expected

Comment: my OS is windows 10 English

Comment: Take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how). You also might need to make sure that the font you are using in the windows command prompt has support for those characters. Also, consider trying it in powershell - I believe powershell has much better unicode support.

Comment: these characters are normal Chinese characters, I tried in powershell, it shows square.

Comment: Thanks guys, I fixed this issue by install Chinese OS language and reboot computer.